# PHP: What's the most efficient way to summarize a large array into just 10 arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

My web app returns to the user all images in a specific folder (pictures taken for each day in the month) via array of filenames. Issue is that sometimes the number of images are just too many (30-500 images).

What i wanted to do is provide a summary of that array, by reducing that array to just 10 images. I could easily get the first 10 by limiting the loop. But that just represents the first part (for few images of the day) . I wanted to get 10 images from that array in a way that the 10 images is equally spread out throughout the day.

I could think of several ways to do this but involving quite a lot of code.

Was wondering if anyone knows of a cool array function or method that solves this problem?

Comment: `I wanted to get 10 images from that array in a way that the 10 images is equally spread out throughout the day.` - see, that sentence defines the logic. Now, instead of us figuring out what the author wanted to achieve, why don't you explain the algorithm in a proper, logical way using IT terminology? I'd say your question is unclear, but you're obviously doing two things - figuring out this algorithm I mentioned and thinking about efficiency. Focus on one, explain it clearly, show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function in php for do that. The best thing I think is using of `sizeof()` function:

```
$size = sizeof($array);
$chunkSize = ceil($size/10);
for($i = 0;$i<$size;$i+=$chunkSize){
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$images = ... //result from database
$result = [];

$total = count($images);
$index = round($total/10);

for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i += $index) {
    $result[] = $images[$i];
}
```